# How to make the top menu bar shorter and smaller in VS

Tags: visual-studio, menu, settings

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU1w1.png)
I want it to be shorter and not big. But I'm looking for something in the settings and can't find it. Is there anything that can help me, pls?

I want it to be shorter and not big. But I'm looking for something in the settings and can't find it. Is there anything that can help me, pls?

Answer (score 0):

In Tools - Customize - Commands - Menu Bar you can delete unused top level menus to make the top menu bar shorter.